# How to get innerText of child div

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, innertext, getvalue

```
<span class="info">
    <span> Child 1 </span>
</span>
<span class="info">
    <span> Child 2 </span>
</span>

$('#result').on('click', 'span', function() {
var search = $(this).children(".info").val();
```

I want to access the text written inside the child element of the clicked element.
It does not work with the .val function that wrote above because there is no value.
How can I do it with innertext function ?

If the top span is clicked, the value of the search variable should be Child 1, if the bottom span is clicked, its value should be Child 2.

Thank you.

Comment: no `result` element present in code given

Comment: I didn't write that part, it's in the code above

Comment: no is not, there is no HTML element with the id `result` the reason why the below answer works it's because he added a div container with that id to your HTML assuming that the `result` id belonged to a div

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/).

```js
$('#result').on('click', 'span.info', function() {
  let search = $(this).find('span').text();
  console.log(search);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
  <span class="info">
    <span> Child 1 </span>
  </span>
  <span class="info">
    <span> Child 2 </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: The function works, but it doesn't just take text, it also takes spaces. For this reason, it cannot find the data when querying from MySQL.

Comment: @BoraÖzçağlar Spaces are part of the text; you have spaces in your HTML, so it is returned. You can use `$(this).find('span').text().trim()` to remove the leading and trailing spaces.